# ion-menu create own type or change existing animation and behavior

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm looking for a way to add a menu to my app. However, this has a different behavior than the existing `<ion-menu type = "push">`.

Do you know a possibility to create your own type or to change an existing type?

Here is a picture of what is very similar to my goal. The menu opens with a push across the screen. The existing screen will also be smaller. A Click or swipe on the current page (on the right) will close the menu. It seems like the menu is fix behind the current page.

The menu should be a component or something similar.

Optional it would be nice to have a drag and drop like movement like Material Design recommend it for a Backdrop Component (https://material.io/design/components/backdrop.html#usage)

[image: sidemenu screenshot unknown app]

Am I on the right track with the ion menu or can you name a better one?

Answer (score 1):

Since your animation is very complex for the default ion-menu, you should better build your own component.

Here are some resources to help you : a [codedrop](https://tympanus.net/Development/SidebarTransitions/) demo to help you build the menu and a [tutoriel](https://www.joshmorony.com/custom-components-in-ionic-2/) to encapsulate it in  your own custom ionic component.

Good luck in building this !

Comment: Do you have a solution for a component that shifts the current page? Does the page have to be in the component?

Comment: I’ve no pre made solution but the linked codedrop can definitely help you to code you own solution. No, you dont need to put the page component in the component, a custom header at the same level of the ion-content and some good css/js and you’re ready to go 